# Deployment options for asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-deployment

I need to deploy asp.net mvc solution which has about 13 projects in it. I need
My web project is running using default web server that comes with VS2013 not as a separate IIS app

a) To deploy to our dev server directly from my local visual studio

- **I need to be able to modify code on the dev server(Just the GUI)**

b) Deploy to production, no modification of code allowed.

c) Give non-raw files which is ready to run to other developers who
   are in different geography.
 - **I don't want them to modify my files, just run my       application    on their local machine.**

SQL server will be on a different server and IIS/Application is on a different server in production. In dev all of them are on the same machine

The main project is called webgui and the other ones are helper projects. What is the efficient way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to create a publish profile and use that. You specify things such as the server address and credentials in here. You can have multiple profiles if required for different destinations.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Once this is set up you can publish directly in Visual Studio by right clicking your MVC project and selecting "Publish"

Answer (score 0):

There is no deployment scenario that will allow you to actually modify code. So that's out. As far as modifying database connection strings and the like, anything configured in Web.config can modified per deployment using config transforms. All you need to do is set up different project configurations. By default, you get `Debug` and `Release`, but you can add additional ones by going to "Configuration Manager..." under the "Build" menu in VS.

Then, when you publish the project, select the appropriate configuration and any associated transforms will be applied to the resulting published Web.config.

For more information on Web.config transforms see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx